# How much memory can I actually allocated on a cuda card

Tags: cuda

I'm writing a server process that performs calculations on a GPU using cuda. I want to queue up in-coming requests until enough memory is available on the device to run the job, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how much memory I can allocate on the the device. I have a pretty good estimate of how much memory a job requires, (at least how much will be allocated from cudaMalloc()), but I get device out of memory long before I've allocated the total amount of global memory available.

Is there some king of formula to compute from the total global memory the amount I can allocated? I can play with it until I get an estimate that works empirically, but I'm concerned my customers will deploy different cards at some point and my jerry-rigged numbers won't work very well.

Comment: Interesting. It was my impression that you could allocate the entire global memory space, maybe less a small amount. Is your graphics card being used by anything else in the system? If you're using CUDA 4.0, you might be able to check using the cuda tools SDK or an already-built tool... I'll test my system right now and see whether I have the same problem.

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that I'm using cufft, which I can't track directly, but the docs say it can take upto 3x the FFT size in memory. It doesn't seem like nearly enough to account for the discrepancy.

Comment: What GPU are you using? How much global memory does it have? Check with the deviceQuery tool in the SDK. I just played around a little and it looks like I can easily allocate 1208/1280 Megabytes of global memory on ym GTX470, *with a single call to cudaMalloc* no less. There's a strong possibility that CUFFT is responsible; otherwise, there may be a memory leak in your program. Are you calling cudaFree like you should? Could be a memory leak in a lib you're using.

Comment: It's a Quadro 600 with 1G of memory. I have my cudaMallocs and frees wrapped in a pointer class. I added tracking and print statement and I can see that I don't have leaks. Also the server can run a long time with small jobs without any problems, so a leak is unlikely.

Comment: And how much memory can you allocate before it craps out? It seems like a worst-case estimate using CUFFT and memory size N is going to be something like n = (T - k) / 3, where T is the total advertised global memory, n is the amount you use with CUFFT, and k is a small overhead amount. Taking your k to be 5/6 mine = 60MB and T = 1024 MB, you're looking at an n of around 321 Megabytes. How much are you actually getting?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your reasoning, but I can allocate about 542M. The next attempt of 640K fails. That means I'm using slightly over half the memory, not accounting for cufft, when it fails.

Comment: Based on the number 542, my model would predict that you have inherent overhead of 60 MB, between 211 and 422 MB of CUFFT-related memory and between 331 and 120 MB of non-CUFFT-related memory. (The first way assumes CUFFT uses 3x the memory profile, the second 2x). If your usage is falling inside that envelope, I'd say that everything is making *perfect* sense. If you would like me to explain the derivation of the model in more detail, let me know and I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of your GPU's DRAM is an upper bound on the amount of memory you can allocate through `cudaMalloc`, but there's no guarantee that the CUDA runtime can satisfy a request for all of it in a single large allocation, or even a series of small allocations.

The constraints of memory allocation vary depending on the details of the underlying driver model of the operating system. For example, if the GPU in question is the primary display device, then it's possible that the OS has also reserved some portion of the GPU's memory for graphics. Other implicit state the runtime uses (such as the heap) also consumes memory resources. It's also possible that the memory has become fragmented and no contiguous block large enough to satisfy the request exists.

The CUDART API function `cudaMemGetInfo` reports the free and total amount of memory available.  As far as I know, there's no similar API call which can report the size of the largest satisfiable allocation request.

Comment: I believe the word is "contiguous".