# How to calculate the largest possible float array I can copy to GPU?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am wondering how to calculate the largest possible float array that I can transfer from my host to GPU device?
My GPU specs:

```
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s)

Device 0: "GeForce GT 650M"
Total amount of global memory:                 1024 MBytes (1073414144 bytes)

( 2) Multiprocessors, (192) CUDA Cores/MP:     384 CUDA Coreslayers

Total amount of constant memory:               65536 bytes

Total amount of shared memory per block:       49152 bytes

Total number of registers available per block: 65536

Warp size:                                     32

Maximum number of threads per multiprocessor:  2048

Maximum number of threads per block:           1024

Max dimension size of a thread block (x,y,z): (1024, 1024, 64)

Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)

Maximum memory pitch:                          2147483647 bytes
```

Comment: if you want to have one big contiguous array,it is 1024 MB (the size of the global memory)  / sizeof(float) = 268435456.

Comment: You can transfer whatever size array you can successfully allocate using `cudaMalloc`.  This will depend on how much free memory is available on your GPU, which can't be discovered from the `deviceQuery` output.  Your GT650M is probably hosting a display, which uses some of the available memory.  You can discover how much free memory you have with the cuda runtime API function [`cudaMemGetInfo`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__MEMORY.html#group__CUDART__MEMORY_1g376b97f5ab20321ca46f7cfa9511b978).  The size of array you can allocate will be somewhat smaller than that

Comment: @m.s. Shouldn't it be 268353536. That's the number I get when using the bytes in parenthesis.

Comment: There are many similar questions on the [cuda]() tag, such as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687610/how-much-memory-can-i-actually-allocated-on-a-cuda-card).  You might want to search the cuda tag on "cudaMemGetInfo".  I'm pretty confident this question is a duplicate of one of them.

Comment: There is no chance, under any circumstances, that you would ever get an array of the size @m.s. is suggesting allocated or copied to that GPU.

Comment: That was very helpful @RobertCrovella , and yes the answer of the question you mentioned is my answer. Thanks.